# Struct array assignment in c

Tags: c

How can i get this to work? The struct array elements can be random and element in the array can vary. I tried creating a pointer and assigning each records separately but no luck.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct _str
{
    int arraySize;
    int a[10];
} str;


int main()
{
    str s[50];

    s[10] = {4, {1, 4, 5, 6}};
    s[20] = {3, {2, 7, 11}};
    s[30] = {3, {3, 8, 9}};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you want `rand()`?

Comment: what exactly do you need?please elaborate.

Comment: @Koushik I ran it, it shows the error `expected expression before '{' token|`

Comment: You can not set elements of an array like that. Consider doing like this separately:
s[10].arraySize = 4;
s[10].a[0] = 1;
s[10].a[1] = 4;
s[10].a[2] = 5;
s[10].a[3] = 6;

Comment: @Koushik Can you explain why?

Comment: @SheerFish i have answered it.

Comment: Answering Koushik's question - There is a python script which looks for orders to be fulfilled every few seconds spits out a struct array. The c program is then complied and results are displayed thru a url. At maximum, there would be 50 open orders. But I am not sure what order ids would be there in the array list. so instead of declaring an array will NULLs, and assigning values where there are vaild orders, I want an struct array, I want to assign data in array index where order are present. In above example, I have only three order to be fulfilled with order ids 10,2030. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

what you are doing is defining the **struct** after its has been **declared**
you can only **assign** to a struct after it has been **declared**

a struct can be declared and initialized in once sentence(i mean during declaration) as so

```
typedef struct _str
{
    int arraySize;
    int a[10];
} str;

int main()
{
  str s[10] = {{1,{2,3,4}},{2,{3,5,6}}....};// this is correct but impractical.
```

//but this is wrong

```
    s[1] = {1,{2,3,4}};//
```

//you have to do this

```
    s[1].arraysize = 10; //explicitly assign each member

    for(int i=0;i<s[1].arraysize;i++)
    s[1].a[i] = value;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am aware of your solutions. I was trying to do in a simpler way if possible.

Comment: @MeUnagi simpler way is this `str s[10] = {{1,{2,3,4}},{2,{3,5,6}}....};` ofcouse simple in the current context is just seclaration and initialization and not readability, productivity etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decide number of elements at runtime use list (Linkedlist,or circular list) as a type instead of array. see  http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html

or use code similar to below

```
typedef struct _str
{
    int arraySize;
    int *a;
} str;


int main()
{
str s[50];

    s[0].arraySize =3;
    s[0].a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*s[0].arraySize ) ;
    s[0].a[0]=2;
    s[0].a[1]=5;
    s[0].a[2]=7;


    return 0;
}
```